# Having issues in aggregate pom

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm facing some issues while deploying application in spring boot. I have following application structure. There are three projects in total 
First project is project Parent and its package type is war
Second project is simple-weather and its package type is pom (I'll add some more maven modules in future)
Third project is simple-webapp and its package type is pom (I'll add some more maven modules in future)

Both simple-weather and simple-webapp added as dependency in parent pom

Here is code

**Parent Project pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjectParent</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectparent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>


  <modules>

    <module>simple-webapp</module>
    <module>simple-weather</module>
  </modules>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <exclusions>

               </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>        
</project>
```

**simple-weather.pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>ProjectParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectparent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>simple-weather</artifactId>

   <properties>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
     <start-class>HelloWorldApplication1</start-class>


    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>        
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

**simple-webapp.pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>ProjectParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectparent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>simple-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>HelloWorldApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>        
</project>
```

So the problem is when i try to deploy parent pom to tomcat, it says following message

> [ERROR]   The project ProjectParent:projectparent:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   (E:\Dashboard\workspace\projectparent\pom.xml) has 1 error [ERROR]
>   'packaging' with value 'war' is invalid. Aggregator projects require
>   'pom' as packaging. @ line 6, column 14

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `<packaging>` of your parent pom must be `pom` like mentioned in the error message. The `<packaging>` of your simple-webapp pom should be war. You just have to switch those.

This value has to be pom for parent packages. Your parent package has two modules: the simple-weather module contains your application the simple-webapp module wraps this application as a deployable war file.

Comment: I cant switch the package of simple-webapp because i'm going to add sub modules in this project. If i change it to war then it won't let me add sub modules

Comment: Either it's a war or it's a parent pom. Further modules belongs to the parent pom and not to the war module.

Comment: @user3257435 why would you add submodules to a project that's really a .war? that makes no sense to me.